# How to do spell-checking throughout my project in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, spell-checking

I am spell checking my project which is developed with android studio. I have multiple files to check spelling. I mean multiple string resource files and a few layouts(I know its a bad practive to have strings directly in layout, but had a little usage and previously developed).

> Is there a way to find the find only the misspelled words? (like we do
>   **find** a word in whole project). I searched a lot and didnt find any solution.

thanks in advance

**Note :** My project is developed only for English. I don't use any other languages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you want to find the words, that you misspelled (write incorrectly) in your project.

To do this you can:

1. In main menu of Android Studio: **Analyze** - **Inspect code** - select **Whole project** - click **OK**
2. In the analyse results find **Spelling**
3. Inside it there will typically be 1 sub-item - **Typo**
4. Inside it you will find all found possible typos (misspelling) over the project including method\variable names as well as typos in the string resources.
5. String resource typos can be found under the module name folders.

Comment: bro i was searching it for a long time thanks. I have a doubt. This search is giving more results like the element ID. can we filter it to search only in the  String elements?

Comment: @jafarbtech, yes I think. It has very powerfull targetting editor, but I don't know how to use it. Too complicated for fast learn, and I can't unfortunately use much time for it.

Comment: Ok no problem.  I can understand that you do many typos. ha haa :)

Comment: Adding on a point, the "Inspect Code" option is present in the "Code" menu. And the results are under "ProofReading"->Typo